# What does this symbol in Hextech Crafting mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

I went through my Hextech Crafting loot and I noticed that some of the skin shards I have display a symbol that looks like a ward while other skin shards don't.

[image]

What does this symbol mean? I originally thought that it had something to do with the amount of essence each one disenchants into, but the Butcher Urgot shard and Outback Renekton shard are worth the same amount of essence as well as the same amount of RP in-store.

Comment: It means the item in question is Legacy. Things you can't currently buy from the shop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That symbol indicates a legacy skin (a skin that you can no longer buy in the shop).  [Source](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-balance/sykujRf0-hextech-crafting-what-do-these-symbols-mean)